# overloading [] and , c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

So suppose we have this expression

```
auto x =Object.operator[][1,2,3,4];
```

I want my C++ code to insert the numbers 1 2 3 4 to a vector that is located inside the object my code is below.

```
class Object{
    Object operator[](int temp){
        this->x.push_back(temp);
        return *this;
    }
    vector<int> x;
};
int main()
{
    auto x =Object().operator[][1,2,3,4];

   return 0;
}
```

This code doesnt compile. As far as i have understood i have to overload comma and [] but i cant figure out how to do this.I am new to C++.

Edit  extra question.!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Check code below that is my update.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class List{
    public:
    List(){}
    List(int a){
        x.push_back(a);
    }
    ~List(){}
    int operator[](int a){

        return a;
    }
        const char* operator[](const char * a){
        return a;
    }

    vector <int> x;
};
int main()
{
    List x = List{}[1,2,3,4];


   return 0;
}
```

Thanks to you guys i am close to the answer i am searching.How can i add all the values included in [] to some vector for example and send it to list and add to its vector.There comma operator will be overloaded but i dont know how.As far as i know and i can understand is that i have to put an object before 1 and the overloaded comma will be called but i cannot do that.is there any other special syntax that would call it.

Comment: `Object.operator[][1,2,3,4]` doesn't look like valid C++ syntax. I don't think any combination of overloads would get that to compile.

Comment: You would be better off providing a variadic member function template. The usage would be something like `Object.insert(1,2,3,4);`.

Comment: And note that your operator[] had better actually return a reference or this is pretty much useless even if you get it to work.

Comment: If you're new, I suggest you learn how to program in C++ before trying to adapt its syntax into something silly.

Comment: you really should not change semantics of an operator. That type of construct is not going to be intuitive to anyone and is likely to cause problems for anyone who uses it.

Comment: To overload an infix operator at least one of the two expressions must be of class type. There is no way to change the semantic of `1,2,3,4` because they are numbers, not class instances and the comma will behave as the standard comma (evaluating 1, 2 and 3 in sequence and ignoring the result and keeping only 4).

Comment: Why do you want to do this? I would really not expect that to imply appending elements. It looks like a read operation, not a write operation.

Answer (score 1):

A possible, straight-forward way to do this without comma overloading would be:

```
class Object
{
public:
    template<typename Numbers = std::initializer_list<int>>
    Object &operator[](const Numbers &numbers)
    {
        std::copy(std::begin(numbers), std::end(numbers), std::back_inserter(x_));
        return *this;
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> x_;
};
int main()
{
    Object object;
    auto &obj = object[{1,2,3,4}];
    std::vector<int> numbers = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    obj = obj[numbers];
    return 0;
}
```

Some noteworthy changes:

- class member visibility
- operator[] is more generic and returns a reference
- caller accepts by reference

Comment: Since you are using C++11 features anyway, why not use `std::initializer_list` as the argument for `operator[]`? You are constructing a temp `vector` from an `initializer_list`, so just eliminate the temp `vector` and enumerate the `initializer_list` directly

Comment: Could you give an example?

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's just a toy example, but you're right: the temporary is superfluous. In fact, further improvements are possible. I've edited the example accordingly.

Comment: `auto &obj = Object{}[{1,2,3,4}];` creates a dangling reference

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to use the [] operator in C++ to insert a list of numbers to your object's vector.

If that's the case, you can make use of C++11's implicit conversion. Here's a sample code:

```
class Object
{

public:

    Object operator[]( vector<int> vx )
    {
        v.insert( v.end(), vx.begin(), vx.end() );
        return *this;
    }

private:

    vector<int> v;
};
```

This way you can use:

```
Object o;
o[{1, 2, 5}];
```

to insert the list "1, 2, 5" to your object's vector easily. The {1, 2, 5} will be implicitly converted to a vector of integers and your custom [] operator function will be called and executed.

Comment: `Object operator[]( vector<int> vx )` should probably be `Object &operator[]( const vector<int> &vx )`

Answer (score -1):

The `operator[](int)` is a binary operator. It can't be overloaded to take more then 1 index argument.

here some working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Object{
  public:
    Object operator[](int temp){
        this->x.push_back(temp);
        return *this;
    }
    vector<int> x;
};

int main() {

    auto x = Object();
    x[1];
    x[2];
    x[3];

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question of how to achieve the requested syntax. If the requested syntax isn't possible or advisable, then you need to say _why_ that's the case before you offer alternatives.

Comment: operator[] ist a binary operator. you can only call x.operator[](3) or equivalent x[3].

Comment: Note the question also suggested overloading the comma to allow passing multiple arguments, so you should address that in your answer, too.

Comment: But you can pass initializer list as argument: `obj[{1,2,3}];`